# R: Plot of the relationship between lambda values and coefficients in ridge regression

Tags: r, regression-coefficients, regularization, ridge-regression

I'm using the code below to plot the relationship between the lambda values used of ridge regression and the coefficients:

```
lambda_array <- 10^seq(2, -2, by = -.1)

ridge_reg <- glmnet(X_train, 
                   y_train, 
                   alpha=0,
                   lambda=lambda_array)

plot(ridge_reg, xvar = "lambda", label=T)
```

[image]

However, I am getting an unfamiliar output as shown in the image above. This looks like what I would get when plotting the goodness of fit instead. For that I apply:

```
plot(ridge_reg, xvar="dev", label=T)
```

Which also gives an unfamiliar output:
[image]

I am clueless about what might be happening here.

Some information about the dataset:

- contains several categorical values which were encoded using the ordinal method.
- data was split into testing and training sets which were scaled and converted into matrices in order to use glmnet.
- The values for RMSE, Rsquared and adjustedRsquared (for the optimal lambda of 0.01) are:

```
[1] 0.2586564
[1] 0.9999986
[1] 0.9999986
```

The code to compute the values above is:

```
# y_actual = y_test
# y_predicted = y_pred
rss <- sum((y_pred - y_test)^2)
tss <- sum((y_test - mean(y_test))^2)

# RMSE
RMSE <- sqrt(rss/nrow(df_encoded))
RMSE

# R squared
r_squared <- 1 - (rss/tss)
r_squared

# Adjusted R-squared
adj_r_squared <- 1 - ( ( (1-r_squared)*(nrow(df_encoded)) )  / ( nrow(df_encoded)-ncol(X_train)-1 ) )
adj_r_squared
```

I was wondering if someone could please explain to me what might be happening here.

Comment: The `glmnet` documentation ask to not set lambda, it is better to use the default NULL setting, so the code does the chosing. Did you try that?

Comment: I did, but when using cv.glmnt() instead. I actually posted a different question (not answered yet) about it because the default value of lambda and the one specified in my range were way too different: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/520030/r-interpreting-optimal-values-of-lambda-for-ridge-regression-the-using-both-def